# Cancel button in searchBar ios 8

Tags: search, ios8

tell me how to change the text on the Cancel button in searchBar?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G1ZM.png

Comment: Show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that in this delegate method of UISearchBar

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:NO];
    for (UIView *subView in theSearchBar.subviews){
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
            [(UIButton*)subViewsetTitle:@"Button Title"forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

***UPDATE***

after a long way searching the only way i got working in swift

is to set a custom UIBarButtonItem but you will need to show the search bar on the navigation

in ViewDidLoad()

`self.searchDisplayController?.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true`

and in Delegate Method

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        var barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Button Title", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "here")
        self.searchDisplayController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    }
```

i hope that works with you

***«Another UPDATE***

as you said in comments you will need to localize your application, in your case you will only need to localize the storyBoard

first navigate to your project settings then info, under localizations click the + button and add your own languages then check only StoryBoard

and now you have localized your app but you might don't see the changes until you remove the app and install it again or if the device language is set to english you will need to write 2 lines of code to change the language manually here is it

```
var str:NSString = "ar" // ar stands for arabic you put here you own language small character 
        var myArray:NSArray = [str]
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myArray, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
```

and your button will looks like this

[image: locale]

if you want to know more about localization see this [Internationalization Tutorial for iOS [2014 Edition]](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014)

if you still need help till me :)

Comment: Is it possible to do it on Swift?

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. Thank you

Comment: there is another way but you will need to use an objective-c class in your project will you want to do that ? and can you tell me why you want to use another title , if you want to use another title for another language you can let the system do that for you by localizing your application and cancel will be changed based on the current langauge automatically

Comment: This is due to another language. I think that it is enough to change the language

Comment: How to make this localizing?

Comment: i'll write an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions.

1. set key/value

[self.searchController.searchBar setValue:@"취소" forKey:@"_cancelButtonText"];

This solution works well, but you have to know that _cancelButtonText property is not public property.(You can not find this property in the documentation page.)
And It's not sure that this solution can pass the apple review process. So, use solution 2 please.

2. use a delegate.
   You can change cancel button title(iOS8) within willPresentSearchController method.

(Assume that the searchBar is in tableView headerView)

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{

    // You have to set YES showsCancelButton. 
    // If not, you can not change your button title when this method called 
    // first time. 
    self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

    UIView* view=self.searchController.searchBar.subviews[0];
    for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {

        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            // solution 1
            UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;

            [cancelButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"취소", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    }
}
```

Also, You can get infomation about the searchBar through a view debugging tools in Xcode. Set a breakPoint at the willPresentSearchController method. 
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the cancel button is not a top view in the Search bar. You should  search for it recursively.

```
-(UIButton*)findButtonInView:(UIView*)v{
    for (UIView *subView in v.subviews){
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
            return (UIButton*)subView;
        }else if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]){
            UIButton* btn = [self findButtonInView:subView];
            if(btn){
                return btn;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

//...

UIButton* searchButton = [self findButtonInView:self.searchBar];
```

Comment: how convert this method to swift?